# Infinite loop in windows service

Tags: java, windows-services

I have a strange problem that my microphone mutes itself every now and then. So I decided to write a windows service that will unmute if it is muted. Here is all the code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Unmute
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        unmute();
    }

    public static void unmute() {
        Line.Info[] thisLineArr;
        Line.Info thisLineInfo;
        Line thisLine;
        BooleanControl mute;
        Mixer.Info[] infos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        try {
            while (true) {          
                for (Mixer.Info info: infos)  
                {  
                    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
                    if (mixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE))  
                    {  
                        thisLineArr = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();              
                        thisLineInfo = thisLineArr[0];
                        thisLine = mixer.getLine(thisLineInfo);
                        thisLine.open();
                        for (Control thisControl : thisLine.getControls()) {
                            if (thisControl.getType().equals(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE)) {
                                mute = (BooleanControl)thisLine.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE); 
                                if(mute.getValue()) {
                                    mute.setValue(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        thisLine.close();
                    }  
                }
                Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I used Java Service Wrapper and installed this code as a service. Everything is working fine, but what is bothering me is infinite loop that I have in the main function. Is it all right to have an ifinite loop or there are better solutions for my problem?

Comment: Your code is fine, as long s this `sleep()` stays there. Otherwise you will most likely use 100% of one core.